# Determine whether the following is a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-transformations

I attempted to solve this question but the book answer guide says it's not a linear transformation (no reasoning provided).
Question is: is the following a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3 $to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$L(\mathbf{x}) = (1+x_1,x_2)^T$

My attempt was

- $L(\alpha\mathbf{x}) = (\alpha(1+x_1),\alpha x_2)^T = \alpha((1+x_1),x_2)^T = \alpha L(\mathbf{x})$
- $L(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = ([(1+x_1)+(1+y_1)], x_2+y_2)^T = (1+x_1, x_2)^T  + (1+y_1, y_2)^T = L(\mathbf{x})+L(\mathbf{y})$

I thought this was good enough to say it's a linear transformation, but maybe I'm missing something very basic... (and sorry in advance I didn't put this into proper matrix notation, I'm new to this formatting thing). If I'm wrong, does it have to do that the 3rd dimension of **x** is going unused?

Thank you all, I misunderstood how $L(\alpha \mathbf{x})$ gets transformed and fell apart from there :)

Comment: Are you sure that $L(\alpha\mathbf{x}) = (\alpha(1+x_1),\alpha x_2)^T$?

Comment: $L(\alpha x) = (1 + \alpha x_1 , \alpha x_2)^T$ so you've made an error in that step.

Comment: How careless of me... thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint:  Any linear transform must send your 0 vector to the 0 vector.